# jQuery's append doesn't append but removes

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="invrows">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="rowrow">
            <td><input type="text" id="idef" name="idef[]" class="required"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="iprice" name="iprice[]" class="required"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="ivat" name="ivat[]" class="required"></td>
            <td><div id="addrow">Add One More</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And want to ADD a new row to the table each time the "addrow" div is clicked.
So this is my jQuery code:

```
$('#addrow').click(function(){
        $('#invrows tr:last').append($('#rowrow'));
});
```

However, instead of adding a new '#rowrow' row (sounds rediculous, I know), it just removes this one row, and thus leaving me with an empty table.
I tried adding the HTML code for the row to .append(), and this works just fine, but I want it to work with the DOM element, so that when the original row changes, nothing is broken, and the jQuery code itself doesn't need editing.
All help appreciated!

Comment: as a rule of thumb, if it sounds ridiculous, it probably is, naming conventions are a godsend ;)

Comment: ;) were all guilty of breaking some best practices (i wont call them rules) at some point

Comment: using a string is more beneficial. `.append('<div id="rowrow">stuff</div>);`

Comment: @Beneto: beneficial? Perhaps, but less maintainable.

Comment: @borniet well it works lol

Comment: @beneto lol, tru :-) Most of the time that is the real criterium :-) But right now, I want something extra ;-)

Comment: @Broniet is it an element that is already in the DOM? If so would a 'get' function help? Or even an initial variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append a clone of the row, and not the original row itself. Additionally, you should remove your id value so as to not duplicate it on cloned elements:

```js
// Use event-delegation since we'll have many rows
$("#invrows").on("click", ".addrow", function (e) {

  // Clone row
  var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

  // Append to table, clear inputs
  clone.appendTo(e.delegateTarget).find(":input").val('');

  // Remove add button from original row
  $(this).closest("td").remove();

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/4MRx5/

Comment: And this is also a problem when user has filled the text fields before pressing the add button.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to the row, not the body. You want something like:

```
$('#addrow').click(function(){
        $('#invrows tbody').append($('#rowrow').clone());
});
```

Oh, and as others said, either clone the element or get the html for it directly. (edited code to reflect this).

Also, you'll end up with two rows with the same id, which isn't really good either. :)

One more thing, looking at the docs for [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it looks like it is actually required or else jquery just moves the actual element around. See the examples there.

Comment: This is not correct because the html does not include the actual <tr></tr>, thus adding table data directly to the body.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is append the html content of rowrow so instead try:

```
$('#addrow').click(function(){
    $('#invrows tr:last').append($('#rowrow').html());
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should not use append(). With this you will insert the ne table row inside the parent one. I think you need to use after() for your purpose.

```
$('#addrow').click(function(){
        $('#invrows tr:last').after($('#rowrow').clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns a new row for you to append.

```
function newRow (table) {
    var html = '<tr id="rowrow' + (table.tBodies[0].rows.length + 1) + '">' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="idef" name="idef[]" class="required"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="iprice" name="iprice[]" class="required"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" id="ivat" name="ivat[]" class="required"></td>' +
        '<td><div id="addrow">Add One More</div></td>' +
    '</tr>';
    $(table.tBodies[0]).append(html);
}
```

here it is in use:

```
var $table = $('#invrows');
$('#addrow').click(function(){
    $table.append(newRow($table[0]));
});
```

Now if you need to modify the structure, you just do it in the newRow function. You could alternatively use a templating engine.

**Note, you still have a duplicate ID problem with all of your inputs and the addRow div.**